# What is the point in backing up a docker container?

Tags: docker, image, backup

I have started using Docker recently and currently running Portainer and Nginx.

Of course, I've also started looking deeper into Docker, how it works, how to back it up, and I just feel like I'm missing something.

The data, whether it be bind mount or volume, resides on the host, when all is said and done.

I followed some video showing how to backup a container, export an image and reimport it, and once I reached the end I realize that you still have to run the command with all the ports, mounts, etc. like if I was simply using the original image. Of course, since the data isn't backed up, you have to move it manually.

What am I missing? What's the difference between backing up an image as opposed to just pulling a new one with docker run command that you used the first time and moving the data?

Comment: I am indeed talking about exporting an image. At first, my impression was that it would backup your customization, like ports and whatnot, but it doesn't seem to be the case, so what does it actually backup, compared to a freshly pulled image?

Comment: Tbh, I have never used it. It might be of benefit if we have "*faster means*" (fast internal network, or a USB stick) to transfer the image instead of pushing and pulling it to a registry.

Comment: Not really a programming question...but you're right, you should never need to back up a container, and I've never run `docker export` at all.  (Manage containers the same way you do individual processes.)